# How to build eglibc in debug mode

Tags: compiling, debugging

I am trying to create a debug version of the eglibc to allow step by step debugging in a program that crashes in the eglibc.

I want the created ".so" file to be as close as possible to the eglibc that comes with my version of Ubuntu (14.04 x64) (with the same options, patches, etc.) with the exception of the debugging facilities.

So far I am having a hard time finding an exact procedure to do that. It is becoming frustrating and time-consuming, so would anybody be kind enough to provide that procedure to me, please?

Comment: See here https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/glibc

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Using debuild instead of make and configure seems to be a good start, however the eglibc is still built with the -O2 flag. I opened a ticket on launchpad as it seems to be a bug. Meanwhile I will see if I can hack the script used by debuild.